# How to use google font offline line in polymer?

Tags: css, polymer, google-font-api

I want to use a Google font locally, not online. How can this be done in polymer?  I know polymer does not support `font-face`. Has any one done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Do it via the `<link>` tag.  For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"/>
```

Then you can use `font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;`

Edit:
Or, if you insist on local (which I personally don't recommend),  you can copy the CSS code from the URL of the font and paste it in your own code.  However, this way is more difficult and not as speed-efficient.